# How can I configure my asterisk to work with meetme

Tags: asterisk

I try to use commend MeetMe(...), but i get from the CLI this response "pbx.c:3695 pbx_extension_helper: No application 'MeetMe' for extension (test_main, 600, 1)"

I try to use ztdummy but i can not successful instell that.

Can anyone help me, or refer me to the place when i find answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try running `core show application MeetMe` -- if it says the application is not found, then check `modules.conf`.

If `autoload=yes` is not specified, then you need a `load => app_meetme.so` directive.

It would also be helpful to have your asterisk version as well as the snippet of your extension logic that is failing.

Comment: thenks,
The version is 1.6.2.20. 
When i write "core show application MeetMe" i get the answer "-bash: core: command not found".
In modules.conf the "autoload=yes" is specified.
In the extension the code is this:
exten => s,n,Answer()
exten => s,n,MeetMe(600,i,4444)

Answer (score 0):

As you stated "I try to use ztdummy...", well You need a timing source for MeetMe. 1.6x has a timing source without the hardware, but MeetMe still uses it. You should by any means install ztdummy or maybe Dahdi. Here is what works for me:

```
rpm -qa|grep dahdi
dahdi-devel-2.3.0.1-0
dahdi-2.3.0.1-0
kernel-module-dahdi-2.3.0.1-0_2.6.18_164.el5
kernel-module-dahdi-xen-2.3.0.1-0_2.6.18_164.el5

lsmod|grep dahdi
dahdi_dynamic_ethmf    15940  0
dahdi_dynamic_eth      10772  0
dahdi_dynamic          14280  2 dahdi_dynamic_ethmf,dahdi_dynamic_eth
dahdi_transcode        12164  1 wctc4xxp
dahdi_voicebus         45248  2 wctdm24xxp,wcte12xp
dahdi                 197320  24 opvxd115,rcbfx,r1t1,rxt1,ax1600p,dahdi_dynamic,ap400,ystdm16xx,ystdm8xx,opvxa1200,xpp,dahdi_transcode,wcb4xxp,wctdm,wcfxo,wctdm24xxp,wcte11xp,wct1xxp,wcte12xp,dahdi_voicebus,wct4xxp,wanpipe
crc_ccitt               6337  2 wctdm24xxp,dahdi
```

Did you give a shot to ConfBridge? New engine for conferences.